# Visual Deconstruction of Sentence Wanted

Tags: syntax

> In the halcyon days of English learning in Japan, dating back as far
>   as the Meiji Era, it used to be that, unlike recently, when, alas,
>   much emphasis has been placed blindly on practical communicative
>   “skills,” those who bravely chose to set foot in the interminable
>   forest of the language saw “art” therein, finding the whole purpose
>   and meaning of their noble endeavour in so honing their “craft” that
>   they might dabble in poetical flourishes, or enjoying Shakespeare, in
>   their second tongue.

Vexingly,I find myself in over my head with structural parsing of this.
I would appreciate it if you could kindly furnish me with some kind of visual aid that plainly shows the syntactic framework of the verbose sentence.

Comment: Which part of the sentence's structure do you not understand?

Comment: Is this by, or about, Nitobe Inazō?

Comment: @StoneyB Not really in fact, but the author, methinks, had Nitobe and Natsume and the like in mind when he wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

The core sentence is this:

> those saw “art” therein.

A dummy subject *it* permits the writer to recast the "actual" main clause, *those saw art*, as the complement of the verb *be* in an *it* cleft:

> It used to be that those saw “art” therein.

*Therein* is a preposition phrase complementing *see*, with *there* referring to the *interminable forest of the language* and explaining where they saw the art.

This is a temporal locative modifying that recast main clause, telling when this state obtained:

> In the halcyon days of English learning in Japan,

This is a supplement glossing the temporal locative:

> dating back as far as the Meiji Era,

This is a supplement glossing the main clause:

> unlike recently,

And this is a further supplement, a relative clause glossing *recently*:

> when, alas, much emphasis has been placed blindly on practical communicative “skills,”

This is a relative clause modifying (defining) *those*

> who bravely chose to set foot in the interminable forest of the language

This is a supplemental ger-ppl clause glossing the original main clause:

> finding the whole purpose and meaning of their noble endeavour in ... honing 
>   their “craft” .. or enjoying Shakespeare,

This his is a *so .. that* construction modifying *honing their craft*

> so .. that they might dabble in poetical flourishes,

And this is a preposition phrase modifying the conjunct object of the preposition *in*, *honing their “craft” .. or enjoying Shakespeare*

> in their second tongue.

The entire sentence is wittily contrived to exemplify the “dabbling in poetic phrases .. in their second tongue” which former Japanese students of English  delighted in—a delight which the writer clearly shares!

Comment: Ger-ppl=gerund-participle?

Comment: @user178049 That's right. I get tired of typing that awkward term. I may take to calling it a "gerple".